# How to find the inverse laplace transform of [F(s)/s]^n

Tags: laplace-transform

Let $F(s)=\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}$, we have $\frac{F(s)}{s}=\mathcal{L}\{\int_o^tf(x)dx\}$. How  to find $\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\left(\frac{F(s)}{s}\right)^n\right\},\text{ for}~ n\in \mathbb{N} $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253613/convolution-laplace-transform). Here is a start for the case $n=2$,

Let

> $$ g(t)=\int_{0}^{t} f(x)dx .$$

Now, recalling the fact

> $$ \mathcal{L}(g*h) = \mathcal{L}(g) \mathcal{L}(h), $$

we have

> $$ \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\left(\frac{F(s)}{s}\right)^2\right\}=(g*g)(t)=\int_{0}^{t}g(\tau)g(t-\tau)d\tau .$$

You can simplify the above integral by interchanging the order of integration and see what you get. Try to generalize this answer.

Comment: This is really good point to know, at least for me. :)

Comment: @B.S.: Happy that have found it useful. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: You are welcome.