# Laplace transform of two functions

Tags: laplace-transform

I know how to do a basic laplace transform, but how does one deal with transforming complex combination of functions?

For example, how would we handle:

$$\mathcal{L}\left( \ \sqrt{\frac{t}{\pi}}cos(5t) \right) = ... $$

From a table of laplace transforms it is known that:
$$\mathcal{L}\left( \ \frac{cos(5t)}{\sqrt{\pi t}} \right) = \frac{e^{-5/s}}{\sqrt{s}}$$

This table value must be of some use to solve this problem, but how?

EDIT: Can we use $\mathcal{L}\left( f(t) *g(t) \right) = \mathcal{L}\left( f(t)\right) * \mathcal{L}\left( g(t)\right) $?

Comment: There's a relation between $\dfrac{d}{ds} \mathcal{L}[f](s)$ and $t\cdot f(t)$. Which?

Comment: There should be an identity for the Laplace transform of $t.f(t)$ if $\mathcal{L}(f(t))$ is known.

Comment: Hrm -- there's a known identity for taking the transform of $g(t)f(t)$ where the transform of $f(t)$ is known?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Use the property

> $$ L(t f(t)) = -F'(s). $$

**Added** Note that,

> $$\frac{\sqrt{t}}{\sqrt{\pi}}{\cos(5t)} = t \frac{\cos(5t)}{\sqrt{\pi t}}.$$

Now, take Laplace transform of both sides of the above equality

$$ \mathcal{L}\left\{ \frac{\sqrt{t}}{\sqrt{\pi}}{\cos(5t)}  \right\}= \mathcal{L}\left\{ t \frac{\cos(5t)}{\sqrt{\pi t}} \right\}=-\frac{d}{ds}\frac{e^{-5/s}}{\sqrt{s}}=\dot\,. $$

Comment: Is $F'$ the transform of $f(t)$ or the derivative of the transform of $f(t)$?

Comment: It's the derivative of the transform.

Comment: @Bob: It is the derivative of the Laplace transform of the function which is in your case $f(t)=\frac{\cos(5t)}{\sqrt{\pi t}}$.

Comment: So what would $t$ be in this case?

Comment: @Bob: I'll add more material.

Comment: I see. So if t was raised to the second power we'd do $(-1)^2F''(s)$ instead? Can we use $L{f(t)*g(t)} = L{f(t)}*L{g(t)}$ instead?

Comment: @Bob: Convolution is different: $L(f*g)=L(f)L(g)$. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253613/convolution-laplace-transform).

Comment: It is? We couldn't take $f=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{t}}$ and $g=cos(5t)$ and then compute the transforms manually without any tables?

Comment: @Bob: You should take your time to understand these concepts and distinguish between them. You should solve more problems.