# Inverse Laplace Transform : $\mathcal{L}^{-1} \left \{ 2\cdot s^{-1}\cdot e^{-3\cdot s} \right \}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I need to find the inverse laplace transform below. Is there any trick for this question? I tried but I couldnt find it.

$$\mathcal{L}^{-1} \left \{ 2\cdot s^{-1}\cdot e^{-3\cdot s} \right \}$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is a [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253613/convolution-laplace-transform).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left\{ \frac{1}{s} \right\}=1=f(t)$$ and  $$\mathscr{L}^{-1}\{e^{-as}F(s)\}=f(t-a)\mathscr{U}(t-a),~~a>0$$ where $a=3$.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any table or something for these equations? I didnt know this equation.It would be great.

Comment: @g3d: An elementary table would be [this](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/Laplace_Table.pdf).

Comment: @B.S.: Very clear and concise +1

Comment: I agree with Sami! +1