# Solve Laplace Integral (3 factors)

Tags: integration, laplace-transform

Please provide steps to solve this integral:

> $$3\int^t_0{\sin{u}(t-u)e^{-(t-u)}du}.$$

Comment: What progress have you made?

Comment: None. I fail at the integral having 3 factors and none of u' or v' for partial integration disappear

Comment: This is the convolution of the two function $\sin t$ and $t e^t$.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal correct. But how do we solve it?

Comment: @user1211030: You can use integration techniques.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal That's a great suggestion, thank you

Comment: @user1211030: I post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a start.

$$ f(t) = 3\int^t_0{\sin{u}(t-u)e^{-(t-u)}du} = 3e^{-t}\int^t_0{\sin{u}(t-u)e^{u}du}  $$

$$ = 3te^{-t} \int^t_0{\sin{u}\,e^{u}du} - 3e^{-t} \int^t_0{u\sin{u}\,e^{u}du}. $$

To make it easier to evaluate the last two integrals use the identity

> $$ \sin u = \frac{e^{iu}-e^{-iu}}{2i} $$

**Another approach:**

We can use the [fact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253613/convolution-laplace-transform)

> $$ \mathcal{L} (g*h) =  \mathcal{L}(g) \mathcal{L}(h).$$

Taking the Laplace of

> $$ f(t) = 3\int^t_0{\sin{u}(t-u)e^{-(t-u)}du} $$

gives

> $$ F(s) = \frac{1}{(s^2+1)(s-1)^2}. $$

Using partial fraction we can have the form

> $$ - \frac{1}{2(s-1)}+\frac{1}{2(s-1)^2}+\frac{1}{4(s-i)}+\frac{1}{4(s+i)}.$$

Now you can use the tables of Laplace transform. I think you can finish the problem.