# Laplace transform convolution attempt

Tags: integration, examples-counterexamples, laplace-transform, solution-verification, integral-transforms

I can't seem to get this Laplace working using the convolution method.

$H(s) = \frac{1}{s^2(s+2)}$

Which I can't get to work using convolution. So I am separating it into $\frac{1}{s^2} * \frac{1}{s+2}$ and then I think I go from here with convolution?

How do I do this?

This takes forms $t$ and $e^{-2t}$

So I plugged it into the theorem and I got $\int_o^\tau (t-\tau)e^{-2\tau} \mathrm{d\tau}$ which gives me $2t$, but this is not the answer in the book? What is wrong?

> Nevermind I got it, I will post a self answer soon(Integral above forgot to do int by parts).

Answer (score 1):

We can find the inverse Laplace transform by taking Mellin inversion formula. In the problem, we have a simple pole at $s=-2$ and a pole of order two at $s=0$.
\begin{align}
h(t) &= \mathcal{L}^{-1}\{F(s)\}\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma - i\infty}^{\gamma + i\infty}\frac{e^{st}}{s^2(s+2)}ds\\
&= \lim_{s\to 0}\frac{d}{ds}s^2\frac{e^{st}}{s^2(s+2)}+\lim_{s\to -2}(s+2)\frac{e^{st}}{s^2(s+2)}\\
&= \frac{2t - 1 + e^{-2t}}{4}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

To find the inverse Laplace you need to take the convolution of the functions $x$ and $e^{-2x}$. See a [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253613/convolution-laplace-transform).