# inverse laplace transform of F(s)

Tags: laplace-transform

Let $f(x)$ be some arbitrary function 
, $F(s)$ is laplace transform of it

I think

inverse laplace transform of 
$\frac {F(s)}{s+r}$

where, r is constant

may be $\int_0^t e^{-rt'}F(t') dt'$

however, the answer is $\int_0^t e^{-r(t-t')}F(t') dt'$

why it is like that?

Thanks

Comment: Could you explain why the proof-verification tag is on this question?

Comment: sorry, I removed it, I thought that tag is for proof or verification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the property:

> the Laplace of the convolution equals the product of the Laplace, i.e; $\mathcal{L}(f*g)=\mathcal{ L }f \mathcal {L}g  $.

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253613/convolution-laplace-transform).

Comment: @eric: You are very welcome!